# Estimate using central limit theorem

Tags: random-variables, central-limit-theorem

> Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be independent random variables, uniformly distributed over the unit interval $[0, 1]$. Let $a$ be a real constant number satifying $\frac{n}{2} \leq a \leq n$, and denote $Y = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$. Estimate $P(Y \geq a)$ using the central limit theorem.

My attempt:

First observe that $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ have a common mean of $\frac{1}{2}$ and a common variance of $\frac{1}{12}$, let $Z = \frac{Y - \frac{n}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{12}}}$, we have $P(Y \geq a) = P(Z \geq \frac{a - \frac{n}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{12}}})$.

My question:

How should I do next to proceed? The normalized value is expressed in terms of $n$ and is it okay to express this inequality with function $\phi$ in terms of $n$? Also, how should I do to change from $a$ to $n$?

Comment: Isn´t $P(Y\geq a)\approx 1-\Phi(0)=0.5$ if $a=\frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: @callculus could you please tell me why $a = \frac{n}{2}$ and not $a = n$?

Comment: I mean the case when you calculate the probablility of the lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is OK because convergence in distribution to a continuous distribution implies uniform convergence on the real line. Hence $P(Y \geq a)$ is approximated by $\int_{c_n} \phi (t) dt$ where $c_n=\frac {a-\frac  n 2}{ \sqrt {n/12}}$