# Suppose $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=0$ for all $x$ and $f_n$ non-increasing and continuous. Is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(n)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=0$ for all $x$ and $f_n$ non-increasing and continuous.  Is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(n)=0$?

---

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=0$, then
$$
(\forall \epsilon_1)(\exists N_1\in \mathbb{N})(\forall n)(n\geq N_1\implies |f_n(x)|<\epsilon_1)
$$
We want to show
$$
(\forall \epsilon_2)(\exists N_2\in \mathbb{N})(\forall n)(n\geq N_2\implies |f_n(n)|<\epsilon_2)
$$

I belive the above claim is true but the notation involving $n$ is too complicated for me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(x)=-\frac  x n$ is a counter-example. Howver, if you assume that $f_n$'s are non-negative then the conclusion is true since $0 \leq f_n(n) \leq f_n(1)$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Thanks. I have a follow up question for you. If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x)= f(x)$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} g_n=g$ does  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(xg_n)= f(xg)$ ?

Comment: Coincidentally, you answer in another post  answered my question! Upvoted and link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3623048/estimate-using-central-limit-theorem